# Como abrir página no google chrome ultilizando C#

Tags: c#

Preciso abrir uma janela utilizando c# com uma página web específica no Google Chrome (Não no navegador padrão).

Uma possível solução seria executar um javaScript em C#, mas não sei como posso abrir apenas no Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar o `Process.Start()`.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    public  class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
             System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("chrome.exe", "https://pt.stackoverflow.com");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Ajudou bastante, obrigado!